# Constructing new slideshow on new page / same page

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, slideshow

Currently our site has a slide show, however it is rather small.  I'd like to add a new slideshow that shows the original pics in a larger slideshow that runs on Javascript by clicking on a button and then it takes up most of the screen like an interstitial ad would (if it only opens in a new window that is ok).

I've constructed an array of the photos, captions, etc (in php) to send to this page (not sure the best way).  Currently when you click the button, it goes to the new bigger slideshow on a new page, but it doesn't know about the array to from the previous page of pic info.

My question is that I'm not sure of the best way to implement this.

Any advice?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you might consider using an existing module such as [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). The basic idea is that you create a content type that includes an image field, a caption field and, if appropriate, a destination URL, and Views Slideshow then allows you to create a slideshow of them.

The bullet points under "Views Slideshow Installation and Configuration" on that page include links to several tutorials. Here's one that I've used before: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42